# Failed to connect to Mysql at 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql

Estoy usando `Mysql Workbench 6.3 CE` y `Laravel 5.6` con `Laragon` realice la conexión con éxito, pero hoy `Mysql workbench` me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> "Failed to Connect to Mysql at 127.0.0.1 (10061)"

He revisado en la web los tutoriales para resolver este error y me di cuenta que no tengo el service de `Mysql` y tampoco tengo la carpeta bin y no puedo llegar a la solución que muestran  los tutoriales. Trate de desinstalar `Mysql workbench` e instalarlo nuevamente pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

Muchas gracias por su atención y su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Apagas servicios `Laragon`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, das click en botón `STOP`.

2) Cambias la ruta a las carpetas.

```
C:\laragon\data\mysql
```

A

```
C:\laragon\data\mysql.old
```

3)Luego lo inicias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Click en `Start All`

Comment: Disculpa apenas comienzo a empaparme de laravel con Mysql desconozco como probar lo que me comentas.Me puedes indicar porfavor

Comment: En que ruta tienes instalado laragon ?

Comment: Gracias funciono muy bien